# Dynamically updating contents of div element takes two or three tries

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to update the contents of a div, but it's not always working.  I'm not sure if it's relevant to my problem, but I am using jquery mobile.

**Background:**

I have a select menu, which is used to choose a location.  I also have a button which is used to get information about the chosen location.  Ajax is used to fetch the data, which is shown within a div element on my page.  I've found that I need to click the button twice for the div element to update.  Oddly, if I add an alert just before I update the div it works fine (i.e. I only need to push the button once).

**Code:**

```
$( function() {
  $("#weather_submit").click(function(){
    $.mobile.pageLoading();
    var formData = $("#getWeatherForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "weather.php",
      cache: false,
      data: formData,
      success: onSuccessWeather,
      error: onError
    });
    return false;
  });
});

function onError(data, status) {
  $.mobile.pageLoading( true );
  alert('error');
}

function onSuccessWeather(data, status) {
  $.mobile.pageLoading( true );
  //alert(data);  // if I use this line of code I never have a problem (i.e. the weatherSummary div updates appropriately
  data = $.trim(data);
  $("#weatherSummary").html(data);
}
```

I initially found this problem using my Android EVO, but I've just tried firefox and it happens with that too.

I suspect it's something to do with the .html() not doing its job properly for some reason.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: As an experiment I just updated the click handler not to use ajax and instead to update the div directly (I used a counter and had it display "odd" when the number was odd and "even" when it was even.)  This worked perfectly every time.  I'm pretty baffled at the moment.  I know the ajax is working because of the alerts that I have in the onError and onSuccessWeather handlers.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does the `#weatherSummary` element always exist, or is it generated at some point? I suspect something to do with things not loading in time. Try checking your JavaScript error log in Firefox.

Comment: That's a good idea.  I declare it directly in the html so I would expect it to exist, but maybe it doesn't.  By the way, I just tweaked the onSuccsessWeather by putting the alert() AFTER the .html(data) and things always work properly like this.  I'll check the error log.  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't see any javascript errors, but I did see something interesting.  I observed the Post and Response in the javascript console.  The Post is always correct, but sometimes the response wasn't updated (each time I push the button I expect a different response).  It could be that the weather.php script has an error and it's returning stale data, but I don't think this is the case because if I add an alert() it always works.  Is it possible for the jquerymobile stuff to block or corrupt the actual response somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#page_id_name").page();
```

But also I think there is a new method in the Beta 2 update:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/08/03/jquery-mobile-beta-2-released/

> **New “create” event: Easily enhance all widgets at once**
>
> While the page plugin no longer calls each plugin specifically, it
>   does dispatch a “pagecreate” event, which most widgets use to
>   auto-initialize themselves. As long as a widget plugin script is
>   referenced, it will automatically enhance any instances of the widgets
>   it finds on the page, just like before. For example, if the selectmenu
>   plugin is loaded, it will enhance any selects it finds within a newly
>   created page.
>
> This structure now allows us to add a new create event that can be
>   triggered on any element, saving you the task of manually initializing
>   each plugin contained in that element. Until now, if a developer
>   loaded in content via Ajax or dynamically generated markup, they
>   needed to manually initialize all contained plugins (listview button,
>   select, etc.) to enhance the widgets in the markup.
>
> Now, our handy create event will initialize all the necessary plugins
>   within that markup, just like how the page creation enhancement
>   process works. If you were to use Ajax to load in a block of HTML
>   markup (say a login form), you can trigger create to automatically
>   transform all the widgets it contains (inputs and buttons in this
>   case) into the enhanced versions. The code for this scenario would be:

```
$( ...new markup that contains widgets... ).appendTo( ".ui-page" ).trigger( "create" );
```

So if you update to Beta 2 try something like this (untested):

```
$("#weatherSummary").html(data).trigger( "create" );
```

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I am using Beta 2.  Just tried $("#weatherSummary").html(data).trigger( "create" );
 but it didn't work.  I also tried $("#weather").page(); without success.

Comment: I just added a 5 second setTimeout around $("#weatherSummary").html(data) as an experiment and the problem never occurred.  Before trying the setTimeout() I was looking at the XMLHttpRequests with the firefox console.  The Post always looked okay, but the Response had stale data anytime the problem occurred.  I don't understand why using setTimeout would affect what the firefox shows as the Response data and this of course affects what gets displayed in the div.

Comment: Guys, I don't understand this but the problem appears to be that I'm doing some caching in my weather.php script.  I disabled that and everything works fine now.  It doesn't make sense about how the javascript alerts and the timeout stuff made this work.  I'm going to have to dig deaper to get this all sorted.  I'd delete this post if I could because I don't want it to waste anybody's time.